# Decision tree node split by Gini coefficient (used in RandomFerns/RandomForest algorithm)

Tags: python, performance, tree, machine-learning

I am implementing the Random Ferns Algorithm for Classification. For simplicity, let's imagine a single decision tree with only a single node. As input we have a feature and the label of each dataset.

The function should work properly for any number of classes (length of `set(labels)`). The output is a feature threshold which leads to the best split. I plan to further implement other impurity measures such as misclassification rate or entropy.

For those interested in the topic, here is a [link](http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/webis/teaching/lecturenotes/machine-learning/unit-en-decision-trees-impurity.pdf) to a short introduction presentation in pdf format for the topic: classification trees and node split.

My current implementation works fine, yet I am sure there is plenty of place for improvement. If you have question regarding functionality, please ask. I gave some comments which explain what is to be done.

Example input:

```
test_features = [1,2,3,3,4]
test_labels = [0,0,1,1,1]
```

Example output:

```
3
```

Code as follows:

```
def best_split(feature_values, labels):
# training for each node/feature determining the threshold
impurity = []
possible_thresholds = sorted(list(set(feature_values)))

# the only relevant possibilities for a threshold are the feature values themselves

for threshold in possible_thresholds:
    # split node content based on threshold
    # to do here: what happens if len(right) or len(left) is zero
    right = [label for value, label in zip(feature_values, labels) if value >= threshold]
    left = [label for value, label in zip(feature_values, labels) if value < threshold]

    # compute distribution of labels for each split
    right_distribution = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(right)]
    left_distribution = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(left)]

    # compute impurity of split based on the distribution
    gini_right = 1 - np.sum((right_distribution / np.sum(right_distribution)) ** 2)
    gini_left = 1 - np.sum((left_distribution / np.sum(left_distribution)) ** 2)

    # compute weighted total impurity of the split
    gini_split = (len(right) * gini_right + len(left) * gini_left) / len(labels)

    impurity.append(gini_split)

# returns the threshold with the highest associated impurity value --> best split threshold
return possible_thresholds[impurity.index(min(impurity))]
```

This function is used for training of the Random Ferns class such as:

```
 def train(self, patches, labels):

        self.classes = list(set(labels))

        # here uniform distribution for each leaf is assumed
        # for each fern - for each feature combination - for each class - there is a posterior probability
        # these are all stored in a list of lists of lists named 'posterior'
        initial_distribution = [1 / len(self.classes)] * len(self.classes)
        self.posterior = [[initial_distribution] * (2 ** self.fernsize)] * self.number_of_ferns

        #determining the best threshold for each feature using best_split function
        all_thresholds = []

        for fern in self.ferns:
            fern_thresholds = []

            for feature_params in fern:
            # the function feature() extracts the feature values of a
            # specific feature (determined by feature_params) from each patch in patches
                feature_values = feature(patches, feature_params)

                fern_thresholds.append(best_split(feature_values, labels))

            all_thresholds.append(fern_thresholds)

        self.threshold = all_thresholds
```

Comment: @RichardNeumann I improved my code regarding PEP8 compliance and deleted the assert error condition checking. How would you instead check for correct input format/content in productive code if not using assert ?

Comment: @NikolasRieble By condition checking using ```if ... elif... else...``` or exception handling using ```try... except... else... finally...```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Assuming that the `groupby` function comes from the itertools library, the list should be sorted before this function is called. For instance,
   `[len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(right)]` should be
   `[len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(sorted(right))]`. It doesn't work properly if the input is not sorted according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).
2. After you make the split, you compute exactly the same function for the `left` and the `right` part. It might be a good idea to create a separate function for it (something like `get_gini_index(values)`, that takes a list of labels and return the gini index).
3. `# to do here: what happens if len(right) or len(left) is zero`. This one looks sort of weird to me. I'd recommend to figure out whether it's actually a special case. If it is, it should be handled properly (namely, this split should be ignored). If it's possible to prove that it's not a special case, this comment needs to be removed to prevent confusion. I would agree that sometimes `todo`'s can be left in the code, but in this case it looks important and easy to fix.

Comment: Regarding 3) the problem is less a programming issue, than a statistics issue. Further, due to the specific properties of the Random Ferns algorithm, I can not ignore a split. I did not yet find a solution. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the previous answer - which was very helpful - I used the cprofile library as well as the line_profiler the iteratively improve my code regarding performance.

I did use two major improvements which affected the runtime as follows:
For input such as:

```
feature_values = np.random.rand(10000)
labels = np.random.randint(0, high=3, size=10000, dtype='l')
```

- No Improvement: Average Runtime (100 runs) - 76.2324668884 seconds
- First Improvement: Average Runtime (100 runs) - 50.9863730192 seconds
- Second Improvement: Average Runtime (100 runs) - 27.0581687212 seconds
- Third Improvement: Average Runtime (100 runs) - 3.16519999504 seconds (!)

**First improvement** was done regarding the following two lines:

```
right = [label for value, label in zip(feature_values, labels) if value >= threshold]
left = [label for value, label in zip(feature_values, labels) if value < threshold]
```

I substituted them by:

```
selection = feature_values>=threshold        
right = labels[selection]
left = labels[np.invert(selection)]
```

This is better because only once a boolean array is computed and then used for selection twice, whereas in the first code, the selection was done twice (unneccesarily).

**Second Improvement** was done regarding the following lines:

```
right_distribution = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(right)]
left_distribution = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(left)]
```

I substituted them by:

```
right_distribution = list(collections.Counter(sorted(right)).values())
left_distribution = list(collections.Counter(sorted(left)).values())
```

**Third improvement**: Numpy, numpy, numpy

instead of `len(right)` - `right.size`

instead of the second improvement:

```
_ , right_distribution = np.unique(right, return_counts=True)
_ , left_distribution = np.unique(left, return_counts=True)
```

Finally i tried to use the map function instead of the `for threshold in possible_thresholds:` loop. This did not yield any relevant improvement, therefore I did not include it here. Further I changed some little details to prevent computing the same value twice or computing it in the loop. I am yet working on the code but it now looks as follows:

```
def best_splitV6(feature_values, labels):
# training for each node/feature determining the threshold
feature_values, labels = np.array(feature_values), np.array(labels)

impurity = []
possible_thresholds = np.unique(feature_values)

num_labels = labels.size

# the only relevant possibilities for a threshold are the feature values themselves except the lowest value    

for threshold in possible_thresholds:
    # split node content based on threshold
    # to do here: what happens if len(right) or len(left) is zero
    selection = feature_values>=threshold

    right = labels[selection]
    left = labels[~selection]

    num_right = right.size

    # compute distribution of labels for each split
    _ , right_distribution = np.unique(right, return_counts=True)
    _ , left_distribution = np.unique(left, return_counts=True)

    # compute impurity of split based on the distribution
    gini_right = 1 - np.sum((np.array(right_distribution) / num_right) ** 2)        
    gini_left = 1 - np.sum((np.array(left_distribution) / (num_labels-num_right)) ** 2)

    # compute weighted total impurity of the split
    gini_split = (num_right * gini_right + (num_labels-num_right) * gini_left) / num_labels

    impurity.append(gini_split)


# returns the threshold with the highest associated impurity value --> best split threshold
return possible_thresholds[np.argmin(impurity)]
```

Comment: This function yet is the bottleneck of the target process, if anyone see more chances to improve the runtime, please comment/answer